# chrome-launcher fails to launch chrome

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, lighthouse

I'm using node to run lighthouse and chrome launcher wont launch in my dev env (mac monterey)

It seems like there's something wrong with the dependency - (but typescript compiles)

I think maybe it cant find chrome? But google crhome at /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome

`which google-chrome` returns not found

```js
import ChromeLauncher from "chrome-launcher";

const chromeOptions = {
  chromeFlags: ["--headless", "--disable-gpu"],
};

async function launchChrome() {
  try {
    const chrome = await ChromeLauncher.launch(chromeOptions);
    console.log("chrome running!");
    return chrome;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("**** Chrome failed to launch", e);
    debugger; // always land here.
    throw e;
  }
}
```

error:

```
**** Chrome failed to launch TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'launch')
at launchChrome (webpack-internal:///(api)/./src/server/reporting/lighthouseRunner.ts:35:84)
```

I tried:

- Adding this to my env CHROME_PATH="/Applications/Google
  Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome"
- Adding and removing chrome-launcher from package.json dependancies, deleting node_modules and reinstalling all
  "chrome-launcher": "^0.15.1",
- Making a symlink from Google\ Chrome to google-chrome (it wouldn't run from the terminal)
- Copying Google\ Chrome ot google-chrome, now it's in the path and launches with a warning (below) but chrome-launcher still doesnt launch

````
$ google-chrome
[41560:259:0321/104228.826676:ERROR:keychain_password_mac.mm(103)] Keychain lookup failed: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-25293 "errKCAuthFailed / errSecAuthFailed:  / Authorization/Authentication failed." (-25293)
Opening in existing browser session.
objc[41574]: Class WebSwapCGLLayer is implemented in both /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/WebCore.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/libANGLE-shared.dylib (0x224b7db50) and /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/Frameworks/Google Chrome Framework.framework/Versions/111.0.5563.64/Libraries/libGLESv2.dylib (0x10db57c28). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined." ```


thank you
````

Comment: For me the problem was my VPS didn't have chrome installed

Answer (score 0):

so strange, it worked when i switched to require

`const chromeLauncher = require("chrome-launcher");`

I wonder why.